# Compressing video using created pixel buffer in kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarVideoRange format

Tags: ios, video, video-encoding

I have a bi-planar raw video buffer data in YCbCr format, which I'm using as source to compress one new mp4/mov video in H.264 format on iPhone and iPad. Therefore, I'm using a `CVPixelBufferRef` to make a new pixel buffer and then use an `AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor` to append to the video writer.

However, when I'm calling `appendPixelBuffer` with the new pixel buffer with YCbCr data in it, `appendPixelBuffer` is only returning `YES` for the first frame appended. All the other frames are denied by the writer (by returning a `NO`). The problem is that if I use BGRA32 format raw video data, it's working just fine, so I wonder whether I have a wrongly created pixel buffer with YCbCr format.

I had two methods to create the pixel buffer:

**1)** Use `CVPixelBufferCreateWithBytes`:

```
cvErr = CVPixelBufferCreateWithBytes(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                     videoWidth_,
                                     videoHeight_,
                                 kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarVideoRange,
                                     [videoFrame getBaseAddressOfPlane:0],
                                     [videoFrame getBytesPerRowOfPlane:0],
                                     NULL,
                                     NULL,
                                     NULL,
                                     &pixelBuffer);
```

**2)** Use `CVPixelBufferCreateWithPlanarBytes`:

```
cvErr = CVPixelBufferCreateWithPlanarBytes(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                           videoWidth_,
                                           videoHeight_,
                                 kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarVideoRange,
                                           NULL,
                                           0,
                                           videoFrame.planeCount,
                                           planeBaseAddress,
                                           planeWidth,
                                           planeHeight,
                                           planeStride,
                                           NULL,
                                           NULL,
                                           NULL,
                                           &pixelBuffer);
```

`planeBaseAddress`, `planeWidth`, `planeHeight`, `planeStride` are 2D arrays containing the base address, width, height and stride of the Y plane and the CbCr plane.

So can you show me where I'm doing wrong, or if there is some sample code I can refer to, or if this is iPhone SDK's issue?